# Custom template in joomla. Install Joomla to an existing site

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla-article

I need some help with integrating Joomla to an existing site. The existing site is made of several .php files which shows static text.

I have copied all css and js files to a new template in Joomla and the design seems to work pretty well.

I want to make an article in Joomla for each .php file in the old site containing their 'news'. 
Here's my question: how can i make my template print the article's title and content based on a $_GET id?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the old content in the .php files? In the long run, it might be easier to migrate all of the content into standard Joomla articles, then set your article titles accordingly.

Otherwise, it sounds like you may want a combination of a custom component and some calls to the JDocument object.

Comment: can you explain more about "custom component and some calls to the JDocument object" please? there are about 200 articles so i dont feel like copy-pasting them into joomla manually..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sandbox where we can see your work in action?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clearer.  I was asking if we could see the code, on a public facing server...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code after <head> tag in your template file.

" <jdoc:include type="head" />"